# Java generics : wildcard extends class and include that class

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, extends

Suppose you have this variable :

```
Class<? extends AssetKey<?>> assetKeyClass;
```

Then I can only set `assetKeyClass` to a subclass type of `AssetKey`. Is there a way to do that plus allowing the `AssetKey` class type itself?

Like this :

```
// Subclass
assetKeyClass = TextureKey.class;
// Class
assetKeyClass = AssetKey.class;
```

EDIT :
Forgot to show some class code :

```
public class AssetKey<T> {
// ...
}

public class TextureKey extends AssetKey<Texture> {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Try `Class<? extends AssetKey>`. You will get a warning about using a raw type, but this is AFAIK the only possible way.

Comment: Eclipse gives warnings but not Intellij hmmm. 

Omg you are right! It works but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `extends` (or `super`) bound always includes the bound itself.

The problem in your case is that a class literal, like `AssetKey.class`, always has the type `Class` parameterized by the *non-parameterized* form of that class. So `AssetKey.class` has type `Class<AssetKey>`. And `Class<AssetKey>` is not a subtype of `Class<? extends AssetKey<?>>` because the *raw type* `AssetKey` is not a subtype of wildcard-parameterized type `AssetKey<?>`. (According to Java rules, the raw and parameterized versions of a type are not subtypes of each other.)

On the other hand, `TextureKey.class` has class `Class<TextureKey>`, which *is* a subtype of `Class<? extends AssetKey<?>>`, because the type `TextureKey` (a non-generic class) is declared to be a subtype of `AssetKey<Texture>`, which is a subtype of `AssetKey<?>`.

If you drop the wildcard, and just declare it as `Class<? extends AssetKey> assetKeyClass;`, it will work because `AssetKey` *is* a subtype of `AssetKey`, and thus `Class<AssetKey>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends AssetKey>`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn) commented, the answer is to remove the wild card so that it's :

```
Class<? extends AssetKey>.
```

Now I only need to know why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usage with *extends*

```
Class<? extends AssetKey> assetKeyClass;

// Subclass
assetKeyClass = TextureKey.class;
// Class
assetKeyClass = AssetKey.class;
```

Usage with *super*

```
Class<? super TextureKey> assetKeyClass ;

// Subclass
assetKeyClass = TextureKey.class;
// Class
assetKeyClass = AssetKey.class;
```

Comment: That's not answering my question. Super cannot include subclasses; only superclasses. Is there a way to include the class and subclasses? I need it to be inclusive.

Comment: Both cases work and a code compiles. You use  extends with superclass (AssetKey) or use super with subclass (TextureKey) .

Comment: Hmmmm your answer made me think that I wasn't clear enough in my question.